# how to set openid_identifier in web.config

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have my tokens and such setup in my web.config I just don't know what to put here?

```
<!-- Enter the Application Name by replacing YourAppName -->
<add key="openid_identifier" value="https://openid.intuit.com/Identity-YourAppName"/>
```

The "friendly" name of my app for example is "My Web App". I don't see anything in the application profile where I would set this. Can I set this do anything such as:

```
<add key="openid_identifier" value="https://openid.intuit.com/Identity-mywebapp"/>
```

How does intuit correlate this with my application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you are right. You need to put the app name after Identity-.
However, currently intuit does not correlate this to you app, rather just checks if the url you send is unique. 
In later releases, Intuit might correlate this data, so they have just mentioned this as a guideline to attach your app name with the open id url.